# Не получается передать в метод insert особый аргумент END

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Начал писать на `Python Tkinter`. Так вот когда подключаю библиотеку подключаю её не всю и пытаюсь создать список - `Listbox`, который есть в библиотеке `tkinter`, мне нужно обратиться к методу `insert`, чтобы циклом заполнить список. Когда я обращаюсь к созданному `Listbox` и вызываю для него метод `insert`, `python` принимает только аргументы, куда вставить и что, а в библиотеке для этого метода предусмотрен особый аргумент `END` и как использовать этот аргумент, я не знаю.

```
import tkinter
main = tkinter.Tk()
lis = ["System", "Linux", "Python", "Tkinter"]
ran = tkinter.Listbox(main, selectmode = 'single', height = 3)
for i in lis :
   ran.insert(END, i)
   ran.pack()
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас может выйти ошибка

> `NameError: name 'END' is not defined`

т.к. вам надо указывать откуда вы `END` взяли в данном случае `tkinter.END`

```
import tkinter
main = tkinter.Tk()
lis = ["System", "Linux", "Python", "Tkinter"]
run = tkinter.Listbox(main, selectmode='single', height=10)
run.pack()
for i in lis:
    run.insert(tkinter.END, i)
main.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

так же вы можете использовать без `tkinter.END` используя цифирный вариант т.е. как в данном массиве добавление( добавляется в начало)

```
for i in lis:
    run.insert(0, i)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное вам!

Answer (score 1):

Помимо `.insert()` метода, можно `StringVar` использовать, чтобы значения в список добавить:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Listbox, SINGLE

root = Tk()
list_var = StringVar(value="System Linux Python Tkinter")
Listbox(selectmode=SINGLE, height=10, listvariable=list_var).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Отдельные пункты отделены пробелом в этом случае.

[image: listbox screenshot]

В коде используется форма `from модуль import имя`, которую следует с осторожностью применять, когда при чтении кода из контекста ясно откуда `имя` приходит. Для сторонних модулей, лучше `import модуль` и явное `модуль.имя` в коде применять.